# No "implement interface" option in the quickfix for interface names in IDEA 9, and no clue how to restore it

Tags: java, ide, intellij-idea

Normally in IDEA, there's an option "implement interface" in the quick fix on an interface name:

[image: There's an implement interface option here.]

(The version in this screenshot is IDEA 10, but the feature is not new.)

But I don't have this option since a while ago (don't know exactly when I lost it) and I am not aware what I changed to break it:

[image: No implement interface for me, though.]

(This shot is of IDEA 9, but others with 9 have the option, too.)

Comment: Yes, I had indeed unchecked that option. That I liked. And which is 3 layers deep in the settings. No idea how that happened. Thx anyway, I don't come here every day to say the least! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go to Settings -> Intention -> Declaration -> Implement Abstract Class or Interface and make sure it's checked.